# Read data to be sent to the printer from my computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8

I want to write a program to backup data to be printed from my computer. How can I read data is sent to the printer from my computer? What should I do?

Comment: Why did you tag this with multiple Windows versions? What do you mean by "to be printed from my computer"? Would you just want to create a list of items that need backup and print that list? It would depend on how the printer is attached on how you would read the data, why do you want to get the raw data that is sent to it? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want save document to become PDF file after user printed it. I used Socket API in C# but my printer has static IP and it use LPD protocol - port 515. I can't read data. Can you help me?

Comment: You would have to catch that data before it's being printed. You could try to hook into the Spooler. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964950/making-a-soft-copyfile-of-everything-printed-to-any-printer-from-a-windows-wor) question which would give you start. [Print Spooler API Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162861(v=vs.85).aspx) could also be helpful. Also check [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/459958/windows-7-and-print-jobs-logging). It would suggest there is a default to keep the raw data. Maybe you could catch the event and move it

Comment: Because the user's computer can Window7, 8, 10 or WinXP, ...

Comment: Installing software on each users computer could be quite troublesome. As such maybe consider going for an alternative approach that lets you handle it in a centralized space. Maybe a print server or similar would be an idea?

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm sorry, if my questions bother you because I do not speak much English.

Comment: How to write a program is off-topic for this site, but it could be that a program isn't required to accomplish what you need.  It isn't clear from the question what stage of the process you need to capture--the file that will be printed, the print code sent to the spooler, PDF output, etc.  Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: "When a user prints any file to this particular Windows printer, then automatically capture the bytes that would have been sent to the printer" It is what I want.

Comment: Typically, print jobs don't go directly to the printer.  There is a spooling directory where the print stream is collected as a file and then that file is sent to the printer.  That file sounds like what you want.  There may be a setting to save the spool files after printing, probably accessible from printer properties.  If so, it will be sitting there for the taking.  If not, try taking the printer offline before printing.  That will often let you print and save the spool file until the printer is available.  In that case, just get the file while the printer is still offline.

Comment: Thank you all, I had answer. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/10586/emf-printer-spool-file-viewer